# Converting gradle-java to springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, apache-camel

I need to convert this gradle-java (gradle 6.3, java 8, camel 3.4.2),

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-rest', version: '3.4.2'
}
```

To this (gradle 7.3.3, java 8, camel 3.14.3 springboot 2.7.0),

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

targetCompatibility = '1.8'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-rest::3.14.3'
}
```

But I get this error,
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.apache.camel:camel-rest:.
> Required by:

What should I do?

Thanks
Ric

Comment: Putting two consecutive  ":", `camel-rest::3.14.3`, is just a simple mistake in posting this question, or you've done this in your code too? If not, please post the stacktrace completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double colon,

```
:camel-rest::3.14.3'
```